# Making jQuery UI draggable outside the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag

How to make a `<div>` draggable outside the current window using `jQuery UI`? Currently the `<div>` will stop being draggable when the cursor is out of the window. But if I use `onmousemove` on `window`, it will work (using native JavaScript).

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/u4yKj/ - Try it and you will understand what I mean.

Is there a way to make jQuery to use `window` as the target of the event listener? Because I want it to continue to be draggable outside the window. Thanks.

---

**Using** [image: window] **as the target:**

[image]

> Good.

---

**Using jQuery UI:**

[image]

> Can't get out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is a result of the way jsfiddle has the other frames beside the preview pane.

As you mentioned in your comment on the other answer, the jquery ui demo allows dragging outside the window border. Here is your own jsfiddle in the mobile view and you'll see it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/m/vrq/

It looks the like answer is that as long as you don't have the surrounding frames, it will do what you want... but once you add them, draggable doesn't work the same as your vanilla js implementation.

As far as customizing this behavior you get the following `containment` options:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen - not without changing the code for UI-draggable. You can add containement: 'window' to prevent the sketchy behavior when you get outside the boundaries, but that's about the best you can do.

Comment: But it is possible in jQuery's Demo! http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/default.html